# Enzyme Shallow rendered instance does not inherit props

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

Say I have a component like so:

```
class ExampleComponent extends Component {
  exampleMethod = () => {
    this.props.examplePropFunction()
  }
}
```

I then construct my test like so:

```
it('exampleMethod', () => {
  const examplePropMock = jest.fn()
  const wrapper = shallow(<ExampleComponent examplePropFunction={examplePropMock}/>)
  wrapper.instance().exampleMethod()
  expect(examplePropMock).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

which fails with

```
TypeError: _this.props.examplePropFunction is not a function
```

console.logging it shows it to in fact be undefined.

An easy solution for this is to run:

```
wrapper.setProps({examplePropFunction: examplePropMock})
```

Before taking the instance. My question is, why is that last step necessary?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't necessary, can you check that `examplePropMock` is actually a spy function when you create it and not undefined, do you have latest packages installed? You must be doing something wrong somewhere. I just tested it:

example.js

```
import { Component } from 'react';

class ExampleComponent extends Component {
  exampleMethod = () => {
    this.props.examplePropFunction()
  }
  render() {
    return null;
  }
}

export default ExampleComponent;
```

example.spec.js

```
import React from 'react';
import expect from 'expect';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

import ExampleComponent from './example';

it('exampleMethod', () => {
  const examplePropMock = expect.createSpy();
  const wrapper = shallow(<ExampleComponent examplePropFunction={examplePropMock} />);

  wrapper.instance().exampleMethod();

  expect(examplePropMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

It works when using `setProps` or passing props manually.

Tested with these packages:

```
"react": "^15.6.0",
"enzyme": "^2.5.1",
"expect": "^1.20.2",
```

I used [expect assertions](https://github.com/mjackson/expect) to create the spy instead of jest because I don't use jest but there should be no difference.